# Sprint Boot WebClient with Exception java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-webclient

I'm new in spring boot and trying to code a Server Socket with Spring boot project.The server will send request to other project while using webClient. All project is registered in eureka server and showed in the eureka dashboard with an spring application name

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class Application {
    

    
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public static WebClient.Builder getWebClientBuilder(){
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        ServerSocket server = getServer();
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Server is waiting for connection...");
                Socket connection= serverFront.accept();

                new Do (connection).run();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
            }

        }

    }





    private static class Do implements Runnable {
        private Socket connFront;

        Do (Socket connFront) {
            this.connFront = connFront;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                ...
                    dothings();
                ...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                conn.close();
            }
        }

        private void dothings() throws Exception {
             do something ....
             if(...){
                 OtherProject1();
             }else{
                 OtherProject2(); 
             }
    }
    public static byte[] OtherProject1(String Data) {
        String ResponseText = getWebClientBuilder().build()
                .post()
                .uri("http://localhost:8081/send")
                .body(Mono.just(Data), String.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
        return ResponseText.getBytes();
    }

    public static byte[] OtherProject2(String Data) {

        String ResponseText= getWebClientBuilder().build()
                .post()
                .uri("http://project2/test")
                .body(Mono.just(Data), String.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
        return ResponseText.getBytes();
    }
     
}
```

In OtherProject1 it works fine with localhost in uri but OtherProject2 with will receive an error

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: "SpringApplicationName"
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST http://SpringApplicationName/test [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:156)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:153)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:153)
```

Below is my application.properties file.

```
spring.application.name=project2
server.port=8083


eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
```

I set similar for all the project.Except eureka Server itself.
Did I miss anything to set up in this situation? why is it not working for spring application name here? But when I set up like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class Application {
    
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder getWebClientBuilder(){
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And using Autowired

```
@RestController
public class AppropriationController {
    
    @Autowired
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/test",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String test(@RequestBody String DataReq) {
        String ResponseText = getWebClientBuilder().build()
                .post()
                .uri("http://project3/send")
                .body(Mono.just(Data), String.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
        return ResponseText;
    
    }
```

It works fine with using springApplicationName here. Is it because of the autowiring ?

below is part of the Eureka Server Dashboard with the registered project

[EurekaServerDashBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y1Bc.png)

Comment: is you service showing on eureka server? copy same service exactly(case insensitive), what is the `spring.application.name` value for the service you are trying to connect it must be `SpringApplicationName`

Comment: @silentsudo make some edit with the post.Not sure if it is clear this way. Please help me out Sir. Thank you.